# Address Locator fails at REST

Tags: arcgis-server, geocoding, arcgis-rest-api

I am having trouble publishing my *US Address - Dual Ranges Address Locator* to our ArcGIS Server. I've created it with a very small sample of 7 streets around my local University just to test, with no odd address types (built on *US Census Address Features* shapefile).

It's properly located (myserver\arcgisserver\arcgisresources\Locators) and works when I reference it in ArcGIS Desktop.

Yet when I publish it to our ArcGIS Server, it gives me an error any time I enter a specific house number. Works finding street intersections and even spits back correct addresses if I reverse geocode. But it will not work searching for a specific address.

Anybody understand why this is happening? I am at a loss. I need this to work for my users.

EDIT: I am working in ArcGIS 10.0 SP 5 and ArcGIS Server 10.01.

[image: ArcGIS Editions] [image: ArcGIS Editions]

[image: Working in ArcGIS Desktop]

[image: Working @ REST endpoint]

[image: Failing @ REST endpoint]

[image: Failing @ REST endpoint2]